# Compare 2 JSON (Array of objects)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Example structure of the JSON :

```
{ "array_name1" : [
       {"name":"John","age":"18","group":"user","country":"UK","hobby":"series","sport":"football"},
{"name":"Ted","age":"20","group":"user","country":"US"}, ...]}

{ "array_name2" : [
       {"name":"John","age":"18","group":"admin","country":"UK","hobby":"series","sport":"football"},
{"name":"Ted","age":"20","group":"user","country":"US", sport:"tennis"},
{"name":"David","age":"20","group":"user", sport:"tennis"},...]}

{ "array_name3" : [
       {"name":"John","age":"18","group":"admin","country":"UK","hobby":"series","sport":"football"},
{"name":"David","age":"20","group":"user", sport:"tennis"},...]}
```

I have to compare 2 JSON Array of objects.
I need to compare objects with the same names in the 2 differents array of objects.
For example, I need to compare the array_name1 and array_name2 and I need to detect that a new object appeared in the array_name2. Also I need to detect that the value changed for group on John from user to admin.
If I need to compare the array_name2 and array_name3, I need to detect that the user Ted has been deleted on the array_name3.

Comment: And the problem is... Show your code.

Comment: I don't have any code, I just don't know where to start it from.

Comment: start by googling your title

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```js
var com = { "array_name1" : [
       {"name":"John","age":"18","group":"user","country":"UK","hobby":"series","sport":"football"},
{"name":"Ted","age":"20","group":"user","country":"US"}]};

var com1 = { "array_name2" : [
       {"name":"John","age":"18","group":"admin","country":"UK","hobby":"series","sport":"football"},
{"name":"Ted","age":"20","group":"user","country":"US", "sport":"tennis"},
{"name":"David","age":"20","group":"user", "sport":"tennis"}]}

var com2 = { "array_name3" : [
       {"name":"John","age":"18","group":"admin","country":"UK","hobby":"series","sport":"football"},
{"name":"David","age":"20","group":"user", "sport":"tennis"}]};
var com3 = { "array_name3" : [
       {"name":"John","age":"18","group":"admin","country":"UK","hobby":"series","sport":"football"},
{"name":"David","age":"20","group":"user", "sport":"tennis"}]};
console.log(com.array_name1 === com1.array_name2); // direct compare

function checkEqual(x,y) {
    return JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y);
}
console.log(checkEqual(com.array_name1, com1.array_name2));

console.log(checkEqual(com3.array_name3, com2.array_name3));
```